# Random Double Function - POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to write a function that takes a minimum and a maximum input and returns a double.

Inputs:

```
high (integer)
low (integer)
```

Output:

```
val (double)
```

My SQL code is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_between(low INT ,high INT) 
   RETURNS DOUBLE AS

BEGIN
   RETURN floor(random()* (high-low + 1) + low);
END;
```

The error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "BEGIN"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write this as pure SQL function, like so:

```
create or replace function random_between(low int ,high int) 
returns double precision as $$
    select floor(random()* (high-low + 1) + low);
$$ language sql;
```

Problems with your code:

- the body of the function needs to be surrounded with single quotes (or something equivalent, such as `$$`)
- there is no `double` datatype in Postgres; maybe you meant `double precision`; note, however, that this is an *inexact* datatype: this might, or might not be what you want, but make sure that you understand the implications
- you need to specify the `language` of the function

Comment: it is the first time i create a function in sql, the function can be used for all the elements of a table? for example i have a table of 10 elements which have a `max` and a `min` column.           i would execute my function for all the rows and store the values in a new column called `value`